# Does google SUPL server support LPP protocol?

Tags: gps, location, supl-2.0

I am implementing a minimal `SUPL 2.0 client`. I have added `SUPL ASN1` specification and `LPP ASN1` specification with my application and compiled it. I am trying to implement a `SET initiated Immediate services` scenario.

I have filled all the fields to `SUPL START` message with `LPP` protocol information and `LTE cell id (location id)` information. I am sending this message to `supl.google.com`, but I am not able to receive any response from the `google supl server`.

**Does google supl server support LPP?**

I have tried with `supl.nokia.com` also. Similarly I am not getting any response with `nokia supl server` also.

The same application code is working fine for `RRLP protocol`.

Please let me know if anybody has come across the similar issue or have some information regarding `LPP protocol` usage with `google SUPL 2.0 server`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, supl.google.com supports SUPL 2.0 and LPP.   What port number are you using for the SUPL connection?  I think 7275 is encrypted, 7276 is not.   You could implement OpenSSL or other encryption, but I would just use 7276.

Are you setting the LPP capability bit? Are you sure you got all your asn.1 packing and aligning done correctly?   RRLP working is a good indicator that you know what you are doing, but I think the usual case for no response is a badly formed message.

Comment: Let's make this read like more of an Answer not a question. Want me to edit it?